# Hidden Modal showing when $(document).ready alert called

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a form which contains a modal pop up which is hidden until a button is clicked.

When the page loads, I want to display an alert to the user, and I'm trying to do this using jquery

But when the alert is shown, the modal popup is visible, after I click OK on the alert, the modal popup hides again.
There is obviously a better way to do this, does anyone have any advice?

Here is the code :
Thanks

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
  <style type="text/css">
    .modalBackground {
      background-color: Gray;
      z-index: 10000;
      filter: alpha(opacity=80);
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .hiddenElement {
      display: none;
    }
    .ModalContainer {
      position: absolute;
      display: table;
      background-color: White;
      border: 1px solid Gray;
    }
  </style>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('Logged In');
    });
  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenModalMore" runat="server" />
  <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MoreModal" TargetControlID="HiddenModalMore" runat="server" DropShadow="false" PopupControlID="pnlMoreInfo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlMoreInfo" runat="server" CssClass="hiddenElement ModalContainer">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_More" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">
              Test
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
              <asp:Button ID="btnSave_MoreInfo" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_MoreInfo_Click" />
              <asp:Button ID="btnCancel_MoreInfo" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_MoreInfo_Click" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </asp:Panel>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: do you want an alert or you simple want overlay?

Comment: The modal is separate from the alert. When the page is loaded, I want to check a hidden field in the form to determine if the user is logged in. If so, alert the user. The modal popup should only be shown when a button on the page is clicked.

Comment: You are talking about a JQueryUI dialog, right ?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your modal gets hidden after the document is loaded? So your alert runs first, and then your code hides the popup. If this is the case just add a style to hide your popup initially.

Could you show us the html of your popup so we don't have to guess?

EDIT:
You are overriding your visibility in .ModalContainer -> {display: table;} Either remove that line, or move .hiddenElement after your .ModalContainer so it'd be applied last.

Comment: Thanks, I need to use both these css classes. Have tried your suggestion and changed it to CssClass="ModalContainer hiddenElement" but the popup is still visible on page load until the alert is acknowledged.

Comment: No, I meant the order in the <style> section. Sorry it's misleading.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I have changed the styles so .ModalContainer is before .hiddenElement. The modal is now longer showing on page load but now when I click the button to show the modal, the modalBackground is applied but the actual modal is nowhere to be seen!

Comment: try doing OnClientClick="$('.ModalContainer').show();" on the button

Comment: Same result, modal background applied, no popup

Comment: It seems your popupExtender is complicating matters. Have you read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co ? Another solution would be to use jquery dialog since you are already using jquery (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial style on your modal dialog to display:none in CSS or the element itself where you create it.   If yiu depend in domready to hide elements, they have the potential to flash in view at the start of dorm ready and before window loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change your style with the following:

```
.modalBackground {
    background-color: Gray;
    z-index: 10000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
}
.modalBackground.active {
    background-color: Gray;
    z-index: 10000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
}
.hiddenElement {
    display: none;
}
.ModalContainer {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    background-color: White;
    border: 1px solid Gray;
}
```

And on button click you have to set: `MoreModal.BackgroundCssClass = "ModalContainer active"`